# How can I set a label on all cards in a particular list at once in Trello?

Tags: trello

I have a board with several lists. Three of the lists are "big tasks", "medium tasks", and "small tasks".

I want to make all of the cards on each of these lists a particular color. That way, when I move any card from one of the lists to "doing today", I can see how many big, medium, and small tasks I've assigned, without having to label each card individually.

Is there a way to do this? Or some kind of workaround that would accomplish the same thing (e.g., a simple keyboard shortcut to assign a particular color label quickly, or another system that works better)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not aware that there is currently any way to apply a label to all cards in a list at the same time.  There is a [proposal](https://trello.com/c/DVwrtOzV) on the Trello development board to implement multi-select to make bulk actions possible.

A quick way to individually assign labels is to hover your mouse over individual cards and press <kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> to assign the associated labels.  To see which labels are associate with which numbers, you can press <kbd>l</kbd> (lowercase L) while hovering over the card to bring up the full list of labels.  The number for each label will be displayed in parentheses for each label.

[image: Label Popup]

Comment: My workflow (more than 10 labels): Make label, hover mouse on card, press `L`, enter beginning of label name until it's at the top, hit `Enter`, hit `Esc`, hit `J` to get to the next card, repeat. See also https://trello.com/shortcuts

Answer (score 3):

If you are batch importing a *new* list of items you might like to check out the video on Trello's FB page called "Copy & Paste List Into Trello w/ Members & Labels"

https://www.facebook.com/trelloapp/videos

Simply copy a list of items onto the first card. Before hitting enter, click the dropdown on that card and you can batch add Members and Labels. After hitting enter, Trello will ask if you would like to create separate cards for each item. Hit Yes.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Trello Power-Up, [Butler for Trello](https://butlerfortrello.com) that can do this for you. Unfortunately the free version only lets you create a labeling rule for one column, but it may be valuable enough for you to consider subscribing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Necro, but found this question while looking for the same.

Probably a new feature since this question was asked, but I did the following:

On list in question ('small')

- click ...
- go to automation, when a card is added to this list
- add action
- add label
- select label

This will handle new cards added to your list

Now, to get all the existing ones:

Create a new list ('temp' or whatever)
Back on the first list ('small')

- click ...
- click move all cards in this list
- choose the 'temp' list

Repeat, moving from 'temp' back to 'small'
As the cards are re-added to the original list, they will be automatically labelled

As far as I know, I don't have any add-ons.  We definitely don't have any paid ones.

Comment: This is a great answer. I did something very similar to this and it saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I used this sequence of keystrokes to add a label to a list with 73 cards. For the first card at the top of the list assign the label you want this then adds the label to the top of the suggested label list. Hover the mouse over the next card and do this sequence:

1. <kbd>L</kbd> - to bring up popup label list
2. <kbd>tab</kbd> - to move to the Suggestions
3. <kbd>↓</kbd> - to move to the suggested label you want if not first
4. <kbd>↵</kbd> - press return to select suggested
5. <kbd>Esc</kbd> - to close the label popup
6. <kbd>↓</kbd> - to move to the next card in the list